# Trouble placing P below H1

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I'm trying to put P text below a H1 header, however it seems to bunch the P text up to the right of the H1 div. See image below:

[image]

I want the "Sample Text" BELOW the Sample Header Link". Any ideas?

Code below...

```css
.col_3 #blue_box {
  float: left;
  background-color: #005ea5;
  width: 30%;
}

.col_3 #blue_box,
.col_3 #text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col_3">
  <div id="blue_box">
    <h1><a href="#">Sample Header Link</a></h1>
  </div>

  <div id="text">
    <p>Sample Text. Sample Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the float:left for #blue_box or add clear:left; for the #text.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain this is one of 3 columns - when I add "clear left" it pushes the paragraph below all 3 columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this on your div

```css
.col_3 #blue_box {
  float: left;
  background-color: #005ea5;
  width: 30%;
}

.col_3 #blue_box,
.col_3 #text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col_3">
  <div id="blue_box">
    <h1><a href="#">Sample Header Link</a></h1>
  </div>

  <div id="text" style="clear: both;">
    <p>Sample Text. Sample Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

this will solve your problem

```html
 <div style="clear: both;">
```